# List running command processes on ESX host

Tags: vmware, host, esx

Is there a way to list all currently running command/processes on ESX host something like this `esxcli process list`
I need this to see which commands still running on ESX host.

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of all the tasks running on the ESXi host, you can run the below command

```
vim-cmd vimsvc/task_list
```

Further information on how to use the command can be found at [here](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1013003)

You may also use 'esxtop' to see more details about all processess running in an ESX box along with CPU and memory usage and lot of other performance metrics.

More information about ESXTOP and it's usage can be found at [here](https://www.yellow-bricks.com/esxtop/)

Answer (score 0):

This would fall under the `esxcfg-info` usage. Though it's a bit of a detailed process, so I would check out the following KB: [VMware KB1010993](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1010993)